# I have too many unused storyBoards, Are they affect my project?

Tags: ios, alamofire, uistoryboard

My project run the whole functionality as expect but there is delay it's take one minute sometimes to fill the table view from the JSON API's

Is that happens because I have many unused storyBoards ? ( I was using them for testing purpose )

Notice that I'm using Alamofire to retrieve and send data from API's

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3):

No, unused files does not affect the time of loading data from an API. However, I recommend to delete them to reduce your App size (IPA size) and to improve build time.